# Why cannot import 'TaskSequence' from locust?

Tags: automation, load-testing, locust

I have an old locust file which imports module called TaskSequence from locust.

I have installed locust version 1.4.1.

When I run test file I get message

```
ImportError: cannot import name `TaskSequence`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#changelog-1-0 I saw a mention about this:

Other breaking changes: **TaskSequence** and **@seq_task** has been replaced with **SequentialTaskSet**.